# All Data data gets deleted when simple SELECT request via JPA is fired on a new session

Tags: sql, gwt, jpa, eclipselink, derby

I am finishing a GWT project that is connected to a derby database via eclipseLink, and ORM is done via JPA. On the start I have a login and register button. When I open a session, running the project out of Eclipse, I register a new user and login with this one, everything works fine. When I quit that session now, I can see the user in the Database. When I start a new session now, I can still see the user in the Database. When I try to login now in the new session, the login Button instantiates a new entity manager that connects for the first time again to the database and runs a Select query, to check the user, I try to login with. Everything seems to run fine, as long as I get to that function, which is part of the server-sided implementation of my service.

```
public Fellow getUser(String username) {
    ObjectManager.checkIfOMisOpen();
    EntityTransaction tx = ObjectManager.em.getTransaction();
    tx.begin();
    TypedQuery<Fellow> checkUser = ObjectManager.em.createQuery(
            "SELECT m FROM Fellow m WHERE " + "m.username = '" + username
                    + "'", Fellow.class);
    tx.commit();
    List<Fellow> listUser = checkUser.getResultList();
    if (listUser.isEmpty())
        return null;
    return listUser.get(0);
}
```

The function checks if the ObjectManager, which is a manager for the actions with the database, is open and then trys to get the users with a query. For any reason in this function, ALL objects of the project get deleted.... ONLY when i try to login within a new session...

Does anyone have a suggestion? This is kind a last hours before the deadline big issue :D 
Thanks in Advance

p.s.: here is the persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="...." transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"> 
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>class1</class>
        <class>class2</class>
        <class>class3</class>
        <class>class4</class>
        <class>class5</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.target-database" value="Derby"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" 
                value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" 
              value="jdbc:derby:....;create=true"/> 
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="..."/> 
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="..."/>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="SEVERE"/> 
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Class 3 inherits class 4, and i found out the problem only occurs for mapped relationsships with those objects...

Comment: p.s.: the funny fact is that it worked before, then something changed, probably only generating tables from entities again or sth. and now it does not work....

Comment: Post the persistence.xml properties.  Chances are you are using a drop and create DDL property.

Comment: Set the log level to finest then and post the code to the method where you see the issue.  The log might give you a pointer to what could be happening

Comment: Thx,Chris. The problem occurred with trying to retrieve or save a List<T> item from/to the database. The entitymanager functions are all adequate for the managing scheme of jpa objects and the annotations are set as described everywhere. Though it seems I simply can not write/retrieve lists to the database due to the Serialisation Policy.